# Setting global DNS + MAC address settings on a Debian-based Linux distribution with systemd-resolved + NetworkManager

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, systemd, networkmanager

I'm running a Debian-based Linux distribution, specifically Pop!_OS 22.04 (Ubuntu jammy). I'd like to set custom DNS + MAC address settings globally - that is, to be applied to all network connections automatically, new and pre-existing.

Specifically, I'd like to change the following settings:

- Enable DNSSEC
- Enable DNS-over-TLS
- Change my DNS servers to [AdGuard DNS](https://adguard-dns.io/en/public-dns.html)
- Enable MAC address randomization

Currently, I've created three files that *should* make these changes.

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns.conf`:

```
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/dns.conf`:

```
# specify dns servers
# ignore dhcp-provided

[ipv4]
dns=94.140.14.14;94.140.15.15;
ignore-auto-dns=true

[ipv6]
dns=2a10:50c0::ad1:ff;2a10:50c0::ad2:ff;
ignore-auto-dns=true
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/mac.conf`:

```
[device]
# randomize mac address when scanning for wifi networks
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=yes

[connection]
# randomize mac address upon initial network connection
# retain generated mac address for all future reconnections
# (per-network)
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=stable
wifi.cloned-mac-address=stable
```

After creating these files and issuing a reboot, there's no indication that any changes regarding the network connection have been made.

AdGuard's test page shows that its DNS is "Not Running".

`$ nmcli dev show wlp0s20f3` (Wi-Fi card):

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C6:F5:1A:8E:84:4D
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     NotYourWiFi
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveC>
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.153/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt >
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.0.1, mt =>
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          mbfamily.localdomain
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::70e0:14db:aeb6:b6be/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
```

`$ resolvectl status`:

```
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1
        DNS Domain: mbfamily.localdomain
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search mbfamily.localdomain
```

`/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 192.168.0.1
search mbfamily.localdomain
```

`$ systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf` shows that `resolved.conf.d/dns.conf` *is* being read, however:

```
# /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file, or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the resolved.conf.d/ subdirectory. The latter is generally recommended.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file and all drop-ins.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full co>
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4>
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.go>
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#d>
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no

# /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns.conf
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade
DNSOverTLS=opportunistic
```

Comment: ResolveD priorizes DNS settings from the interfaces, when not explicit deactivated. How about you setup the global DNS via `resolved.conf` instead of using NetworkManager.

Comment: @paladin The `DNSSEC` and `DNSOverTLS` settings, while read by `systemd` (as reported by `systemd-analyze`), were apparently not applied correctly, as reported by `resolvectl` and `nmcli dev show`. So I don't believe editing `resolved`'s configs would help here. Regardless, I don't believe `systemd-resolved` allows for MAC randomization.

Comment: What has a resolver to do with MAC randomization?

Comment: @paladin I want to enable MAC randomization, as I said in my original post. It seems you can't do that with `systemd-resolved`. So using that alone would not work.

Comment: I just noticed that your `wlp0s20f3` uses LLMNR, probably because your NetworkManager is wrongly configured. I'll repeat my other question, what has a resolver to do with MAC randomization? I would guess, nothing. PS I use systemd-networkd for network configuration.

Comment: @paladin NetworkManager's configuration has been untouched aside from the modifications I've already mentioned, though it's possible Pop!_OS's default configuration could be faulty. As for your question, I assume a resolver has nothing to do with MAC randomization. I'm not sure why you're asking this.

Answer (score 0):

This is my systemd-resolved config for DNSSEC and this works.

`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
DNS=9.9.9.9#dns9.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns9.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns9.quad9.net
FallbackDNS=149.112.112.112#rpz-public-resolver1.rrdns.pch.net
Domains=home.arpa
DNSSEC=yes
DNSOverTLS=yes
MulticastDNS=no
LLMNR=no
Cache=yes
DNSStubListener=yes
ReadEtcHosts=yes
ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
```

it's especially important that the following options are deactivated, like so:

```
MulticastDNS=no
LLMNR=no
```

You need to use the stub-resolver from systemd-resolved or the systemd-socket for this to work.

`cd /etc/ && ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf resolv.conf`

Comment: `MulticastDNS` and `LLMNR` default to `no`, at least on my system. Also, `/etc/resolv.conf` is already symlinked to `run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, as seen in my original post. In any case, using the exact values you provided for `DNS` and `FallbackDNS` didn't change anything.

Comment: OK, it seems that `LLMNR` does *not* default to `no`; I assumed the commented values in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` were the defaults. Though I'm not sure where it's being changed to `yes`, in terms of a conf file.

Comment: @unilock Default values are compiled into the program/libraries. You would need to read the source code for double checking. Original Debian usually defaults LLMNR and MulticastDNS values to `yes`.